# ¿Como aplicar un filtro por defecto en una vista Odoo 10?

Tags: xml, odoo

Quiero filtrar los datos mostrados por defecto, estoy cusando Odoo 10.0

```
        <record id="view_tarea_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">tareaa.tareaa.tree</field>
        <field name="model">tareaa.tareaa</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="8" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Tarea">
                <field name="nombre" />
                <field name="descripcion" />
                <field name="terminada" />
                <field name="activa" domain="[('activa','=','True')]"/> 
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Necesito que solo muestre las tareas terminadas de forma predefinida